# Box styled with Tailwind has unwanted margin on top of it

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a Hamburger menu button. But the `button` element has an unwanted margin on top of it.

```
<div class="bg-red-400 w-10 h-10 rounded-md">
    <button class="bg-blue-400 w-full h-full relative focus:outline-none">
        <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
        <span class="flex absolute top-0 w-full h-full relative">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="block transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out bg-black w-8 h-0.5 "></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="block transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out bg-black w-8 h-0.5 false"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="block transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out bg-black w-8 h-0.5 "></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

This code is not complete yet. I need to first this issue.

What is wrong here?

**Update**:

This code also has the same problem.

```
<div class="bg-blue-400 w-10 h-10">
  <button class="w-full h-full">
      <div class="w-full h-full flex flex-col gap-2 bg-yellow-400">
        <div class="bg-white h-0.5 w-4/5"></div>
        <div class="bg-white h-0.5 w-4/5"></div>
        <div class="bg-white h-0.5 w-4/5"></div>
      </div>
  </button>
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

There were pretty much issues with that code.

- Absolute and relative can't be used parallel.
- You are making spans and making them block, why not use div.
- Also flex needs to be directed as columns (flex-col).

```
<div class="w-10 h-10 rounded-md">
    <button class="bg-blue-400 w-full h-full relative focus:outline-none">
        <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-2 absolute top-0 w-full h-full">
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out bg-black w-8 h-1"></div>
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out bg-black w-8 h-1 false"></div>
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="transform transition duration-300 ease-in-out bg-black w-8 h-1"></div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works. But you have nested `<div>` elements inside `<span>` which is invalid HTML. Based on your notes, I updated the code, and remove extra classes. But it still has problems. I need to know the reason so that I won't repeat it again.

Comment: Why without absolute positioning, it does not work?

Comment: you can replace all spans with div, it wont be invalid then.
Not sure why positioning absolute makes it move a bit down, still its not bad practice to use child absolute and parent relative.
Another solution is just make the upper top div "flex" to make the button fit inside.

Answer (score 0):

Can't get the code snippet that you provided to produce anything noteworthy or descriptive, may be work uploading an image example but just from a glance. you are using both absolute and relative classes when you should only be using one here:

```
<span class="flex absolute top-0 w-full h-full relative">
```

change to

```
<span class="flex top-0 w-full h-full relative">
```

Comment: Simple copy paste the code into tailwind's official playground